# Should I keep oil in the refrigerator after deep frying?

Tags: oil, deep-frying

We have a turkey fryer and want to know whether we should refrigerate the oil between uses. We have been refrigerating the oil but it takes up lots of room.

Comment: How long are you looking to keep it for?

Answer (score 1):

I've always stored my used peanut oil in my pantry. I'll strain the cooled oil back into the original container and put it on my shelf.

http://www.seriouseats.com/2013/09/ask-the-food-lab-how-many-times-can-i-reuse-fry-oil.html

Recommendation is a cool, dry place... Not a COLD dry place.